# Add a google map template to YII2 Advanced template

Tags: google-maps, yii2

Actually In our contact page we may display map for a particular address, but in my web site i have different users with different locations, so, when i want to click on that particular user I need to show their address with map. in yii 2

Comment: Actually In our contact page we may display map for a particular address, but in my web site i have different users with different locations, so, when i want to click on that particular user I need to show their address with map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :
Yii 2.0: yii2-google-maps-library.

Installation

The preferred way to install this extension is through composer.

Either run

```
php composer.phar require "2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" "*"

or add

"2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" : "*"

to the require section of your application's composer.json file.
```

Even though there will be plenty of examples on how to use it, here is one that will provide you with a glimpse of its usage:

```
use dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsWayPoint;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\TravelMode;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\PolylineOptions;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRenderer;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsService;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\InfoWindow;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Marker;
use dosamigos\google\maps\Map;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRequest;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Polygon;
use dosamigos\google\maps\layers\BicyclingLayer;

$coord = new LatLng(['lat' => 39.720089311812094, 'lng' => 2.91165944519042]);
$map = new Map([
    'center' => $coord,
    'zoom' => 14,
]);

// lets use the directions renderer
$home = new LatLng(['lat' => 39.720991014764536, 'lng' => 2.911801719665541]);
$school = new LatLng(['lat' => 39.719456079114956, 'lng' => 2.8979293346405166]);
$santo_domingo = new LatLng(['lat' => 39.72118906848983, 'lng' => 2.907628202438368]);

// setup just one waypoint (Google allows a max of 8)
$waypoints = [
    new DirectionsWayPoint(['location' => $santo_domingo])
];

$directionsRequest = new DirectionsRequest([
    'origin' => $home,
    'destination' => $school,
    'waypoints' => $waypoints,
    'travelMode' => TravelMode::DRIVING
]);

// Lets configure the polyline that renders the direction
$polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions([
    'strokeColor' => '#FFAA00',
    'draggable' => true
]);

// Now the renderer
$directionsRenderer = new DirectionsRenderer([
    'map' => $map->getName(),
    'polylineOptions' => $polylineOptions
]);

// Finally the directions service
$directionsService = new DirectionsService([
    'directionsRenderer' => $directionsRenderer,
    'directionsRequest' => $directionsRequest
]);

// Thats it, append the resulting script to the map
$map->appendScript($directionsService->getJs());

// Lets add a marker now
$marker = new Marker([
    'position' => $coord,
    'title' => 'My Home Town',
]);

// Provide a shared InfoWindow to the marker
$marker->attachInfoWindow(
    new InfoWindow([
        'content' => '<p>This is my super cool content</p>'
    ])
);

// Add marker to the map
$map->addOverlay($marker);

// Now lets write a polygon
$coords = [
    new LatLng(['lat' => 25.774252, 'lng' => -80.190262]),
    new LatLng(['lat' => 18.466465, 'lng' => -66.118292]),
    new LatLng(['lat' => 32.321384, 'lng' => -64.75737]),
    new LatLng(['lat' => 25.774252, 'lng' => -80.190262])
];

$polygon = new Polygon([
    'paths' => $coords
]);

// Add a shared info window
$polygon->attachInfoWindow(new InfoWindow([
        'content' => '<p>This is my super cool Polygon</p>'
    ]));

// Add it now to the map
$map->addOverlay($polygon);


// Lets show the BicyclingLayer :)
$bikeLayer = new BicyclingLayer(['map' => $map->getName()]);

// Append its resulting script
$map->appendScript($bikeLayer->getJs());

// Display the map -finally :)
echo $map->display();
```

This extension has also a plugin architecture that allow us to enhance it, so expect plugins to be developed in near future too.

For more info [enter link description here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-google-maps-library/)

Comment: plz accept answer and up vote me